# How to right click and play audio folder on Windows Media Player 12

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, context-menu, playlists

It's always been hard for me to add a music folder with subfolders to Windows Media Player's playlist. I double click a file in the folder (or click on WMP shortcut), WMP opens, and I drag the other files or folders manually to the playlist.

Isn't there an option to add a right-click context menu item that can automatically add all audio contents in a folder (with subfolders) to WMP playlist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows 7 by default this option is available in the right click menu only for optimized folder for music:

You have to change the Folder Option - set it to Music (right click on the folder and select **Properties** and then **Customize** tab)

[image: Folder Options]

Now, when you right click on that folder you will see the option to add it to Windows Media Player.

[image: Add to Windows Media Player list]